# Need a Basic Batch file script for Health Check on Servers

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for a simple batch file that can give me the below details for a list of servers. There is a single domain.

- Hostname
- IP Address
- Domain
- Disk DetailOUs
- CPU information
- Physical memory
- OS details
- Type of server

I have made one myself, but it does not seem to run for a list of servers, it just runs many times for a single server. Please help me, below is the code:

```
for /f %%x in (computers.txt) do systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name" >> C:\temp\output.txt
for /f %%x in (computers.txt) do wmic cpu get name >> C:\temp\output.txt
for /f %%x in (computers.txt) do systeminfo | findstr /c:"Domain" >> C:\temp\output.txt
for /f %%x in (computers.txt) do systeminfo | findstr /c:"OS Name" >> C:\temp\output.txt
for /f %%x in (computers.txt) do systeminfo | findstr /c:"OS Version" >> C:\temp\output.txt
for /f %%x in (computers.txt) do systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Manufacturer" >> C:\temp\output.txt
for /f %%x in (computers.txt) do systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Model" >> C:\temp\output.txt
for /f %%x in (computers.txt) do systeminfo | findstr /c:"System type" >> C:\temp\output.txt
for /f %%x in (computers.txt) do systeminfo | findstr /c:"Total Physical Memory" >> C:\temp\output.txt
for /f %%x in (computers.txt) do ipconfig | findstr IPv4 >> C:\temp\output.txt
for /f %%x in (computers.txt) do wmic diskdrive get size >> C:\temp\output.txt
for /f %%x in (computers.txt) do dsquery computer -name %%x >> C:\temp\output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

if i assume you got list of server name in `computers.txt`.

1. where is server name passed to system info command ?
2. for loop used in your code iterates all line in `computers.txt` and provides output of system info of the machine where it is being executed for every iteration which is not intended.

3.This Process continues till all lines are iterated in your `computers.txt`.

4. use below options to fetch system info from server by using command in the code as

`systeminfo /s /U <<username>> /P <<password %%x
use system info /? for more details`

%%x - will contain the information of file and it changes for each iteration ,it  will contain the corresponding line value in the file.